# To change the status code from 200 to 404 when stepfunction not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-step-functions

I'm trying to Execute the AWS step function from API Gateway, It's working as expected.

Whenever I'm passing the input, statemachinearn(stepfunction name to execute) It's triggering the step function.

But It's still returning the status code 200, whenever it's not able to find the stepfunction, I want to return the status code 404 if the apigateway not found that stepfunction.

Could you please help me on that

Response:

Status: 200ok

Expected:

Status: 404

Thanks,

Harika.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation [StartExecution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_StartExecution.html#API_StartExecution_Errors) API call do return `400 Bad Request` for non existent statemachine which is correct as `RESTful API` standard.

> StateMachineDoesNotExist

> The specified state machine does not exist.

> HTTP Status Code: 400

From the RESTful API point of view, endpoint `/execution/`(which I created in API Gateway for the integration setup) is a resource, no matter it accepts GET or POST or something else. 404 is only appropriate when the resource `/execution/` itself does not exist. If `/execution/` endpoint exists, but its invocation failed (no matter what the reasons), the `response status code must be something other than 404`.

So in the case of the returned response(200) for `POST` call with `non-existent` statemachine it is correct. But when `API Gateway` tried to make the call to `non-existent` statemachine it got `404` from `StartExecution` api call which it eventually wrapped into a proper message instead of returning `404` http response.

```sh
curl -s -X POST -d '{"input": "{}","name": "MyExecution17","stateMachineArn": "arn:aws:states:eu-central-1:1234567890:stateMachine:mystatemachine"}'  https://123456asdasdas.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/v1/execution|jq .
```

```json
{
  "__type": "com.amazonaws.swf.service.v2.model#StateMachineDoesNotExist",
  "message": "State Machine Does Not Exist: 'arn:aws:states:eu-central-1:1234567890:stateMachine:mystatemachine1'"
}
```

Let's say you create another `MethodResponse` where you can provide an exact `HTTP Status Code` in your case `404` which you want to return and you do an `Integration Response` where you have to choose the `Method Response` by providing either `Exact HTTP Responce Code(400 -> Upstream response from the **StartExecution** API Call)` OR a `Regex -> (4\{d}2) matching all the 4xx errors`.

In that case you will be giving `404` for all the responses where the upstream error `4xx` [StartExecution Errors](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_StartExecution.html#API_StartExecution_Errors)

- ExecutionAlreadyExists -> 400
- ExecutionLimitExceeded -> 400
- InvalidArn -> 400
- InvalidExecutionInput -> 400
- InvalidName -> 400
- StateMachineDeleting -> 400
- StateMachineDoesNotExist -> 400

> Non Existent State Machine:

```sh
curl -s -X POST -d '{"input": "{}","name": "MyExecution17","stateMachineArn": "arn:aws:states:eu-central-1:1234567890:stateMachine:mystatemachine1"}'  https://123456asdasdas.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/v1/execution|jq .


< HTTP/2 404
< date: Sat, 30 Jan 2021 14:12:16 GMT
< content-type: application/json
...
```

```json
{
  "__type": "com.amazonaws.swf.service.v2.model#StateMachineDoesNotExist",
  "message": "State Machine Does Not Exist: 'arn:aws:states:eu-central-1:1234567890:stateMachine:mystatemachine1'"
}
```

> Execution Already Exists

```sh
curl -s -X POST -d '{"input": "{}","name": "MyExecution17","stateMachineArn": "arn:aws:states:eu-central-1:1234567890:stateMachine:mystatemachine"}'  https://123456asdasdas.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/v1/execution|jq .

* We are completely uploaded and fine
< HTTP/2 404
< date: Sat, 30 Jan 2021 14:28:27 GMT
< content-type: application/json
```

```json
{
  "__type": "com.amazonaws.swf.service.v2.model#ExecutionAlreadyExists",
  "message": "Execution Already Exists: 'arn:aws:states:eu-central-1:1234567890:execution:mystatemachine:MyExecution17'"
}
```

Which I think will be misleading.